# Deselect ToolStripItem on ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip, toolstripitem

Simple question:

I can `.Select` a `ToolStripItem` (like, if i want a preselected option when opening a context menu strip) but i cannot seem to find a way to set `.Selected` to false or somehow deselect it!

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is private method ClearAllSelections in ToolStrip class, which removes selections from items. You can invoke it via reflection:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(ToolStrip).GetMethod("ClearAllSelections", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
method.Invoke(yourContextMenuStrip, null);
```

All selections will be removed.

Comment: Omfg.... well, Micro$oft at its finest agian :) Make something private when its not supposed to. Well, thanks for answer anyway!

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Great info... Save my time :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the Checked property?

```
public void mnuUncheck()
{
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem Item in mnuStripMain.Items)
    {
       Item.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Checked is a "v" sign near a menu strip item, right? I'm talking about the selection, what happens when you hover over a context menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the approach of Sergey, there is also an internal method on the ToolStripItem which you could call:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(ToolStripItem).GetMethod("Unselect", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
methodInfo.Invoke(yourToolStripItem, null);
```