# ToolStripButton have different behavior on showing Modal Less Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, toolstripbutton

I have a main window and a toolstrip on it with different command buttons. In these commands, I've a 'Print' button too (See Below). When I click on 'Print' button , I need to show sub-form as Modal Less Dialog. Because, I've few option on sub-form. If user select them then he/she can interact with Main Form too.

[image]

Meanwhile, on show() method I disable all controls on Main Form (see below) as it will be done if I use ShowDialog() method to show sub-form. When I click the Print Button, it's color changed which shows it is focused/selected.

[image]

On click sub-form is show like below pic.

[image]

Logically, it should return to previous mode when I close sub-form. But, even sub-form is showing... that 'Print' button on Main-Form is still focused/selected. When I close the sub-form, that 'Print' Button still focused/selected like below.

[image]

What Event/ Property needs to be changed to make this 'Print' Button to show like as it is in initial state.

I've tried Invalidate(), change BackColor but didn't meet the requirement yet. Any Guidelines ?

Comment: Are you handling the Print Button click - or Mouse down - or?  Show your code handling that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Selected Property in ToolStripButton is read only. Anyone, needs to clear the selection of toolstrip buttons can use below method which is invoked via reflections.

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(ToolStrip).GetMethod("ClearAllSelections", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            method.Invoke(yourToolStripName, null);
```

This comes from : [How to Deselect ToolStripItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323224/deselect-toolstripitem-on-contextmenustrip)

Happy Programming.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `CheckOnClick` property of your button to false if you don't want it to appear "selected" at all, otherwise toggle the `CheckState` property on the button when the subform is closed.

Comment: Well, ChekOnClick is false and CheckState= Unchecked in Click Event after Click the ToolStripMenuItem Button. So, what are other options to show the button not selected when click event is fired.